# Оплата на сайте

Tags: php, javascript

Задача такая: необходимо повесить на сайт возможность оплаты картой. После выполнения транзакции необходимо узнать какая сумма была переведена и какие-нибудь дополнительные параметры: например последние 4 цифры карты, или email который был указан при оплате или хоть что-нибудь... И вывести данные на страничке.
Есть удобное решение которое делается за 2 минуты через яндекс деньги. Но там идет просто переадресация на сервис яндекса где все платиться, а возможности получить сколько и кем было переведено я не нашел.
Подскажите???

Добавлю:
Поясню еще чего хочу добиться: вешаю форму на страницу сайта с оплатой от Яндекса, форма содержит одно поле для ввода суммы и кнопка оплатить, при нажатии на кнопку идет редирект на сервис Яндекса - там вводится вся необходимая информация (ФИО, мэил, адрес плательшика, данные карты. Происходит транзакция и вывод ее результата-все это на стороне яндекса, дальше Яндекс показывает кнопку "вернуться в магазин" при нажатии на которую идет редирект на мой сайт). А мне собственно нужно чтобы когда он вернулся на мой сайт я мог показать ему на страничке что он молодец и перевел 100 рублей. Поздравляю

Comment: У всех платежных систем схожий принцип работы. Статистика ведется на стороне платежной системы, в Вашем личном кабинете. Если же Вы хотите сами вести статистику, то существуют колбэки успешной и неуспешной оплаты на Ваш рабочий скрипт, в которой будут указаны необходимые вам данные

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте документацию к любому платежному сервису. Почти все из них при настройке предлагают вам указать некий `callback_url` это адрес, на который платежная система выполнит запрос после успешного выполнения платежа. Туда же она отправит и параметры. Ни одна платежная система просто так не даст вам выдергивать из себя данные, которые вы хотите получить по другому(во всяком случае более простому) сценарию из-за банальнейших соображений безопасности. Я думаю, вы и сами бы не хотели, что бы иной вариант был возможен.

Answer (score 0):

Это называется бухгалтерский учет, и работа с персональными данными (не сарказм). Это действительно важная информация. Информация о платеже у вас в заказе (кто, сколько), информация о статусе в "callback" и в вашем банке.

Информация о кредитной карте? 
Это похоже на [фишинг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3).